# Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages

Tags: android, pdf-generation, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am currently developing android application which is in include "Generate PDF" and "Send mail with out user interacting (Send mail in background)". I am using 4 library. **activation.jar**, **additionnal.jar**, **mail.jar** & **droidText.0.2.jar**. When i run this project it's give error.

```
[2014-10-17 17:58:00 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages;
[2014-10-17 17:58:00 - PdfMail] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages;
```

I see many link. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173704/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-harmony-awt-interna)
But i am not getting right answer. So How can i resolve this?

**Edited**

I solve this problem. I have just replace **droidText.0.2.jar** with **itextg-5.5.3.jar** file.

Comment: Check your project bin -> lib

Comment: I check it. but not working. @koutuk

Comment: do you added any lib double i mean  directly put into lib folder and another for buildpath, remove support lib clean project than add again

Comment: I try with this but same error getting. @koutuk

Comment: Library contain this Class "Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages" Remove that library

Comment: "additonal.jar" and "droidText.jar" in this class "Lorg/apache/harmony/awt/internal/nls/Messages" both are in same class name. & i want to use both class. @koutuk

Comment: is this your custom jar you cannot use same package import

Comment: yes. & i see this link answer. but rename is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173704/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-harmony-awt-interna How can i rename this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio?
if yes, this temporary work around might help

add this to build.gradle:

```
android
{

dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
...

}
```

Comment: No. I am using eclipse luna. How can i resolve in eclipse? @vishal